# Filtering Search Criteria Using If Statement, && and ||

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make the situation like this: user can either fill in "just txtComStartDate" or "just txtComEndDate" or "both txtComStartDate & txtComEndDate".

If user fill in `txtComStartDate` as 18/08/12, only the data from 18/08/12 onwards will display.

If user fill in `txtComEndDate` as 19/08/12, only the data before 19/08/12 onwards will display.

If user limit both `txtComStartDate` 18/08/12 and `txtComEndDate` 19/08/12, the data between these two dates will display.

The `if` statement is giving me error and not working properly. I am confused about the `&&` and `||`. Could someone help? You help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

My code:

```
private void searchComByDate()
{

    // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

        string docPath = fileName;

        xmlDoc.Load(docPath); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {

            XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement)node;

            string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            if (txtComStartDate.Text != (String.Empty) && DateTime.Parse(itemDate) >= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider) 
                || txtComEndDate.Text != (String.Empty) && DateTime.Parse(itemDate) <= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider)
                || (txtComStartDate.Text != (String.Empty) && DateTime.Parse(itemDate) >= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider) && txtComEndDate.Text != (String.Empty) && DateTime.Parse(itemDate) <= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider)))
            {
                string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;
                string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;
                string itemXMLFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

                richComByTemplate.AppendText("SYMBOL: " + itemXMLFile + "\nAUTHOR: " + itemAuthor + "\nDATE: " + itemDate + 
                                            "\nTITLE: " + itemTitle + "\nDESCRIPTION: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i fill in start date, no error. then i tried filling in only the end date, it returns "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: I've added an answer which may help you. I think your operators are getting executed when you don't want them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your short circuiting is failing, because it gets to the `DateTime.Parse(txtComStartDate.Text)` and fails. You should allow it to short circuit when any of those fail to ignore the results:

```
DateTime startDate, endDate;
if ((!DateTime.TryParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out startDate) 
        || DateTime.Parse(itemDate, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal) >= startDate) && 
    (!DateTime.TryParseExact(txtComEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out endDate)
        || DateTime.Parse(itemDate, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal) <= endDate))
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

The way you're going to read this is "Either I can't parse the start date (meaning the user omitted it or it's not valid) or the item date is greater than the start date; AND either the end date can't be parsed (again, either omitted or invalid) or the item date is less than the end date."

Take advantage of the short circuit here. If you can't parse the start date or end date, then it won't bother checking the item date for that boundary. However, because of the `&&`, it will check both (unless the item date is before the specified start date, in which case it can skip the record).

Comment: I got the error saying `No Overload for method TryParseExact take 4 arguments`

Comment: Try it again. TryParseExact requires a `DateTimeStyles` enum to be passed in which I forgot.

Comment: Thanks, it works! :) but one thing is, i am not sure if the timezone is affecting my result. i choose 17/08/12 to 18/08/12, but it will not show the result of 18/08/12. the suspected timezone issue happened since the last time i asked question here after using `CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`

Comment: Try `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` instead of `None`. That should at least force it to use the current timezone (shouldn't matter with regard to the invariant culture being used).

Comment: i found that if i choose 17/08/12 to 18/08/12, the result doesnt show those on 18/08/12, but if i make it 17/08/12 to 19/08/12, then the result doesnt show data on 19/08/12.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to not use the invariant culture provider for the item date when you're using it for the start/end dates as well. Updated my answer to try and account for this by using the same parsing methodology for the item date as well.

Comment: I tried `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` but still the same. the chosen endDate's data will not appear. the chosen startDate's data however do appear.

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this  . A *pseudocode*:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime endDate   = DateTime.MaxValue;


if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtComStartDate.Text))
   startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtComEndDate.Text))
   endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtComEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider);


 DateTime itemDate = DateTime.Parse(itemDate);
 if (itemDate >= startDate || itemDate <= endDate || ...)            
 {
 }
```

Seems more clear that have huge `if` statement with a lot of mixed options inside.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't really know how do i write the `...comparison..`. Do you mean comparing the `startDate` and `endDate`? Thanks.

Comment: @Shyuan: exactly. The *main* point here is to separate comparison options. 1) Init `start` and `end` date limits, after implement comarison.

Comment: could you show me detailed piece of code? If not, it's okay.. I just learn programming 1 month ago.. Im totally lost now..

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a short explanation about the operators:

```
if (a && b) 
    //if both a and b are true

if (a || b)
    //if either a or be is true

if (a && (b || c))
    // a must to be true, and either b or c must to be true
```

Remember they are lazy which means:

```
if (a || b)
    // if a is true, b isn't evaluated
```

If you need more examples or help, please comment :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment that filling in only an end date gave you an error, I would suggest you should probably parenthesise your `if` statement more to force order of operations.

```
if (
(txtComStartDate.Text != (String.Empty) && DateTime.Parse(itemDate) >= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider))
 ||
(txtComEndDate.Text != (String.Empty) && DateTime.Parse(itemDate) <= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider))
 ||
 (DateTime.Parse(itemDate) >= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider) && DateTime.Parse(itemDate) <= DateTime.ParseExact(txtComEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider))
 )
```

You were probably hanging up on `DateTime.ParseExact(txtComStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yy", provider))` which was likely empty, since you were only entering an end date.

**Edit:** Your problem is the short-circuiting of the conditional. If you enter both a `txtComStartDate` and a `txtComEndDate`, your conditional won't make it to the condition (both values entered) since you're using an `OR`. Since having both a start and an end will make the first part of the statement true, it's going to show all nodes that are past your start date; without regard to your end date.

You can do a check for both values before your filter:
`if(txtComStartDate.Text != (String.Empty))`, `if(txtComEndDate.Text != (String.Empty))`

and implement the filtering after doing this- ensuring you get the sure intent of the user.

Comment: When I input both start 18/08/12 and end date 19/08/12, it doesn't filter. it shows all the data from 16/08/12 to 20/08/12.

Comment: @Shyuan You're not showing us the bulk of your sorting, so it's difficult to tell what could be going wrong. I'd try implementing something like Tigran's answer to clarify your sorting structure.

Comment: Hi David, I have updated my code in my original question. that's the function to look for data from XML files. So which item nodes fit the dates chosen will display in richComByTemplate area. Thank you :(

Answer (score -2):

You statement is too complex. Try to extract some conditions to separate properties or methods.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: So offer a suggestion as to HOW he should extract the conditions. This really offers no help.